# How does Maven Dependency Plugin determine used dependencies

Tags: java, maven, servlets

I am working on a Java servlet in a dedicated Maven module.

The Maven Dependency Plugin complains about

```
 [WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:    
 [WARNING]  javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3:compile
```

Apart from not understanding *how* the plugin determines that I am using this dependency, I did declare it then in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

However, then the plugin complains about the following:

```
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3:compile
```

It appears to be a deadlock.

Two questions:

1. Any idea how to overcome this?
2. Any pointer how exactly the
   plugin comes to the conclusion that I am using this dependency?

Additional info:
I am using the dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and this suffices to compile.

Comment: In in eclipse you can view the dependency hirachy. There you should be able to see where this *dependency* comes from.

Comment: I don't get your point. I do not intend to know where the plugin comes from. I intend to understand how the plugin comes to the conclusion that I am using javax.servlet:servlet-api.

Comment: Yes I understand. In the dependcy hirachy view you can see all dependencies used in your project and where they come from. So there  you should see `avax.servlet:servlet-api.` and the dependency in which it is included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin is complaining about the fact that you are *not* using that dependency and therefore suggests that you remove it from your pom. A possible solution would also be that you set the scope of that dependency to `provided` as the servlet classes are provided by the servlet container at runtime:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```